# how to check whether a textfield contains only special characters?

Tags: javascript

I used the below code

```
 var regexp =/^[a-zA-Z]+$/; 
 if(!val.match(regexp)){
 alert("Special characters are not allowed");  
 }
 else
 {
 alert("Required");   
 }}
```

But my problem is that email is one of my form field.The above validation affects my email field.So i just need to check whether all text in a field are special characters.

Comment: I need to check whether the textfield contains only special characters.

Comment: Please find the answer below, let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a regex check for email and change the `regexp` to accept alphanumeric:

```
var emailCheck = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;
var regexp =/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;  // changed
if(!val.test(regexp) || !val.test(emailCheck)){
    alert("Special `enter code here` characters are not allowed");  
} else {
    //enter code here
    alert("Required");   
}
```

Email Regex Courtsey: W3C - http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.email.html

Comment: Rater than *match*, better to use *test*.

Comment: @SimiRajan Please demonstrate your problem in jsFiddle.com so I can help you.

Comment: I want to exclude  datepicker fields just lik email from this check